# Ошибка Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, angular

Пробую передать из Spring Controller ResponseEntity в Angular приложение но получаю ошибку как в Заголовку

**Controller:**

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/addFlight/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> addFlight(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody FlightViewModel flightViewModel){

//Some code...

  return new ResponseEntity<>("Some text", HttpStatus.OK)

}
```

**В Angular Service:**

```
addFlight(flight: IFlight, id: number, places: number): Observable<any> {
const body = {flight, places};
return this.http.put(this.ADD_FLIGH_URL + id, body);
}
```

**Angular component:**

```
public chooseFlight(flight: IFlight, id: number, places: string) {
this.touristService.addFlight(flight, id, Number.parseInt(places)).subscribe(
  (res: Response) => {
    if (res.ok){
      console.log(res.body);
    }else {
      console.log(res.status);
    }
  },
  error =>{
    console.log(error);
  }
);
}
```

В результате чего в консольке:
[image: Результат]

Comment: Скорее всего вы используете ту перегрузку метода `put`, которая ожидает JSON ответ от сервера, а не строку. По идее, если вы укажете что-то в типе возвращаемого значения, то оно заработает. Но вот что указать - это вопрос. По идее в исходниках можно найти нужную перегрузку. Наверное получится что-то типа `put<string>`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло, я могу текст достать в error.error.text но интересует почему оно не заходит в блок res